# gdb binary and where to find it?

Tags: binary-files, gdb, macos-sierra

I'm following the instruction [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin) to install gdb on my MacOS Sierra.

In section "2.1.3. Code-sign the gdb binary", I'm supposed to "specify the full path to the gdb binary" but I don't know what it is and where to find it. Prior to this I'd copied every command [here](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/), up until the line `brew install gdb`, and pasted to my terminal.

I'm new to both the command line terminal and programing, so I'd be really appreciated if someone could explain how to find the path to the `gdb` binary and what it does?

Comment: GDB stands for [GNU Debugger](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gdb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
which gdb
```

Use which to find out where gdb is when you call it - this presumes you already have it installed.